# URL redirect on changing post date - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I updated the date in the post. But the old URL has already gone viral and people end up in a deadlink as page not found. I tried using Simple 301 Redirect Wordpress Plugin and also Permalink Redirect WordPress Plugin. But it does not seem to work.

I want to redirect from http://www.example.com/2014/02/20/events-2014/ to http://www.example.com/2014/03/02/events-2014/

Also all my Mobile apps are synced to the website. I do not want them to get affected because of this redirection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Redirect 301 /2014/02/20/events-2014/  /2014/03/02/events-2014/
```

Or using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^2014/02/20/events-2014/$ /2014/03/02/events-2014/ [L,R=301]
```